# pkg install failing in zone

Tags: solaris, dependencies

Any ideas why I am getting these kind of errors from solaris zone, meanwhile it perfectly works from global zone:

```
root@test:~# pkg install bash
Creating Plan (Running solver): -
pkg install: No solution was found to satisfy constraints

maintained incorporations: None

Plan Creation: dependency error(s) in proposed packages:

    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/ncurses@5.7-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/ncurses@5.7-5.12.0.0.0.105.1
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/ncurses@5.7-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
...
```

Publisher:

```
root@test:~# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris        (syspub)     origin   online T <system-repository>
root@test:~#
```

And global zone:

```
root@urme:~# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris                     origin   online F http://installserver:80/
root@urme:~#
```

And global works as expected, I can install/update anything, but no luck on non global zones. Even I creating absolutely new zone - the same.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems one `-v` does not tell too much while installing. It is possible to use more `-vvvv`:

```
pkg install -nvvvvv xclock
```

This will produce a huge output. In this output i found:

```
Reason:  Package service/file-system/smb is not installed in global zone.
Reason:  Package system/file-system/autofs is not installed in global zone.
Reason:  Package system/file-system/smb is not installed in global zone.
Reason:  Package system/file-system/udfs is not installed in global zone.
```

After i have installed these packages to global zone it allows me to install anything to any NG zone. Do not ask me why do we need `smb` or `autofs` for `bash` or `xclock`...

Answer (score 2):

First, are you sure that it's not already installed on the zone?  `pkg list -a shell/bash`.

Memory is that in v11, zones install the solaris-minimal-server group from IPS.  I find it hard to believe that shell/bash was not part of that group.  Looking at [Solaris 11.2 Package Group Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36807/gmkgl.html#scrolltoc) confirms that shell/bash is part of all install groups which makes sense since there are so many bash scripts as part of the OS.  I think the group clusters were new for 11.2.

It looks like the repo that you're global is pointing to is missing some packages that are needed.  Verify the state of that repo, or try pointing to a different repo (ie: the support repo).

Is svc:/application/pkg/zones-proxyd:default running on the global?  I think this relays IPS requests to the repo(s) pointed to by the global.

What does `pkg info entire` give?